# How to specific "alert" or "info" with logger command in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, logging, rsyslog

I am using a [software](https://www.manageengine.com/products/eventlog/) F, installed on PC named A (192.168.6.5) (running Windows) for receiving log (rsyslog) from a remote Ubuntu 14.04 server B (192.168.6.6). In F, I can see logs from B with types like information, alert, notice...

I made logs in B using logger command:

```
logger "i am log from B"
```

When I checking F in A, I can see the above message, like.

> ubuntu   notice  192.168.6.6   "i am log from B"

When I check the original log file in B, which located at: `/var/log/syslog`,
I can see these lines, but they only have datetime, computerName, messageContent. There are nothing about "info" or "notice". I don't what exact to call it (in F, it is severity). Is there a way to specify it with logger command?

Comment: You mean like with `-p`/`--priority` option?

Comment: Yes. Exact it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `-p` (`--priority`) option, regardless of the name it supports specifying both facility and priority separated by `.` (by default it uses `user.notice`).

For example, for logging a message with `auth` facility and `crit` priority:

```
logger -p 'auth.crit' 'Whatever ...'
```

then check in `/var/log/auth.log` (default location for logs belonging to the `auth` facility).

Similar goes for others. For example, for `user` facility and `info` priority:

```
logger -p 'user.info' 'Whatever ...'
```

Comment: Just a little, is priority information is saved in /var/log/syslog or somewhere? Can I retrieve it later instead of at the logging time only?

Comment: @Andiana yes, of course. As you're in 14.04, just check where the relevant `facility.priority` logs are going, from the `rsyslog`'s configuration file, `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (which should have a include directive to read confs from `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` files too).

Comment: FYI for anyone wondering why this isn't working. It doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu 20.04. For example `logger -p user.crit -t test 'hello'` gives the following in /var/log/user.log: `Jul  6 11:24:54 myserver test: hello`. Notice the lack of priority...